# When was Kenobi planning on training Luke to "save the universe?"

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, obi-wan-kenobi

So, as I understand it, Kenobi and Yoda's plan had been to rely on Luke or Leia to defeat Vader and the Emperor. From the movies or Expanded Universe materials, is there any indication WHEN Kenobi was planning on training Luke to "save the universe?"

Mostly I'm just trying to figure out for myself what the "Master Plan" was. If I remember Episode III's conclusion right, wasn't Bail Organa supposed to organize a rebellion? Was Kenobi planning on the Force to just scream at him when the time was right? Wouldn't you think that when Bail Organa summoned Kenobi he was also sort of counting on him to bring a young, trained Jedi with him to help save the galaxy?

I realize that Kenobi was limited to Luke's training by his uncle and aunt, but you would think that at some point he would have surreptitiously begun training Luke. And I'm not really looking for answers to the second paragraph's many questions. I'm just trying to explain the reasoning behind the initial question.

Comment: What's a universe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll preface my answer only by looking at Star Wars / A New Hope. Clearly, Ben knew there would be a time when Luke could reach a potential for training, since he remained in proximity to Luke.

Ben demonstrated some familiarity with Owen, and Owen's denial to share with Luke any secrets of his true parentage. Ben's frustration shows he did not know Owen would not cooperate in advance. If there was also a distinct plan, I also believe that he would have saved up enough money in advance for him and Luke to leave the planet. Based solely on this movie, I'd say that Ben had no real knowledge of future events but a feeling of the potentiality of future events if Luke made the right choices.

Comment: The Jedi also tend to trust that a way will open for the direction they need to go, so rather than have the money to leave, Ben probably counted on finding a way off Tatooine when the time came.  Also, since he was keeping a low profile, he may have been avoiding towns and cities and places where people might get to know him, which would make earning money tough.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Obi-Wan Kenobi series disrupts Original Star Wars Canon in a number of ways.  As it pertains to the hostility between Obi-Wan and Owen Lars, the series tosses that out the window, since Owen "introduces Obi-Wan to Luke" at the end of the series. That was a totally ridiculous move by the writers, who could care less about Star Wars continuity. Luke seeing a lightsaber 10 years before Episode IV is also problematic to his reaction to his father's lightsaber in the original film.

Answer (score 6):

According to the new (canon) Marvel Star Wars comic; [Star Wars #009](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/52658/star_wars_2015_7), Kenobi's initial plan was apparently to train the boy from an early age. Unfortunately (for him), his guardians, especially Owen, point-blank refused to allow this to happen.

In the absence of a clear force-inspired reason to ignore their wishes, he's stuck on the sidelines making sure that Luke remains safe and that the farm isn't troubled by local toughs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a manner of speaking, yes, Kenobi understood Luke's potential the moment he was born. It's also possible that Qui-Gon Jinn's Force ghost reiterated the necessity of having Anakin's biological son fulfill the prophecy of restoring balance to the Force, which Anakin was unable to do. Between Qui-Gon's Force ghost, and Yoda's astral projection from Dagobah to Tatooine, Obi-Wan was able to "learn as he waited", for Luke to reach the age where he could be pulled away from Owen and Beru, to learn the ways of the Force.